# In aspx page request.QueryString[] is not reading key value in a xml file

Tags: asp.net, xml

How can I read a key value from a xml file using request.QueryString[]. Here is the code I have tried, but its showing `trActivityID` value as null only, if I hardcode the value while debugging only desired page is getting loaded. but I wanted to make it happen at run time automatically.

```
 string ArticleID = "Application"

  try
    {

       strActivityID = Request.QueryString[ArticleID];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strActivityID))
        {
            strArticleURL = GetUrl(strActivityID);
        }

     }
```

Comment: can any one tell solution why queryString is taking null values

Comment: strActivityID is not taking Parameter value can anyone tell me what is the reason. A Response would be appreciable since I'm waiting for a long time